# react-native-video: how to load next video on clicking a button?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, button, video

I have an array of videos, called `VIDEOS [ ]` whose index increments +1 when i click a button. The button fires a function `nextVideo()` .

I'm using react-native-video

How do i get the player to play the next video?
So

```
<Video source={{uri: VIDEOS[currentVideo]}} />
```

needs to reload in my `render()` function in `App.js` with the updated counter called `currentVideo`.

Code below:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    //Video properties
    this.state = {
        repeat: false,
        paused: false,
    };
    //VIDEO index variable
    global.currentVideo = 0;
 }

  nextVideo() { 
    //Skip video when button is pressed to next video in list
    if (global.currentVideo != VIDEOS.length-1)
    {
        global.currentVideo = global.currentVideo + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        global.currentVideo = 0;
    }
   }

 render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.video}>
           <Video 
            source={{uri: VIDEOS[global.currentVideo]}}
            ref={(ref) => {this._player = ref}}
            style={styles.video}
           />    
          </View>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Button
              onPress={this.nextVideo}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
  );
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you show more of your code?

Comment: Yes, it would be great if you can show the outside component and how do you increment the counter.

Comment: Just updated the OP with some code

Comment: Ideally at the end of the nextVideo() function, there should be a way to initiate the video player to use the updated counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to trigger a re-render when you need it is to put video index variable into the state of your component and update it on click.

Here's some code of yours with modifications and comments:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    //Video properties
    this.state = {
        repeat: false,
        paused: false,
        currentVideo: 0, // <-- moved it to state
    };

    this.nextVideo = this.nextVideo.bind(this); //<-- bind method, since we're accessing this
 }

  nextVideo() { 
    //Skip video when button is pressed to next video in list
    if (this.state.currentVideo != VIDEOS.length-1)
    {
        this.setState({currentVideo: this.state.currentVideo + 1}); //<-- use setState instead of assignment to update
    }
    else
    {
        this.setState({currentVideo: 0}); //<-- use setState instead of assignment to update
    }
   }

 render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.video}>
           <Video 
            source={{uri: VIDEOS[this.state.currentVideo]}}
            ref={(ref) => {this._player = ref}}
            style={styles.video}
           />    
          </View>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Button
              onPress={this.nextVideo}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
  );
```

Comment: Genius! I have tried setState before, but i think the piece i was missing was indeed the binding to nextVideo(). So out of interest, does the 'render()' function always refresh? Im just curious to know how my <Video/> latches onto the updated 'currentVideo' index number. Thanks!

Comment: A re-render is triggered whenever the state of a component changes. You can get a better grasp of what's going on by reading through react docs section on State and Lifecycle: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class